# I want to operate a DC 9v relay with a small power

Tags: power, amplifier, relay

Can a lightbulb be switched on using two mobile phones? (Make a call and the bulb switches on)

I need this for a kid's school project so the questions like should the bulb keep glowing after the call ends do not bother. Its for a kid's school project so should be as simple as it could be.

Comment: Do you want to be able to use the phone more than once?

Comment: What sort of relay contact arrangement is required and what sort of load on the contacts is envisaged. These may not seem relevant questions but they are to me.

Comment: Based on a few comments below if using a LED was OK instead of a bulb and it has a vibrator motor you just put a LED and series current limit resistor across the motor. Experimenting with different resistor values and what effect they have might be an interesting kid's experiment as long as you know how to explain it.

Comment: Please don't use sms-like abbreviations. If you take care of the wording and style, you'll get better feedback.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like the circuit below is good enough to switch your relay. I only drew the coil of the relay here.

[image: Cropped Schematic]

*([Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2zt3.png))*

Answer (score 0):

Use the "small power" signal from the speaker output to trigger something like a 555 Timer set up as a one-shot pulse of whatever time you want to hold open a relay, either by driving the relay directly if the small output of the timer IC is enough, or by using a high side MOSFET or BJT as a load switch from the 9V you have available.

The audio style signal will not really be useful for direct amplification to activate a relay switch, unless you like musical relays!

Your relay specifications are quite important for this, so make sure you give it the required current to hold it open. You may also not even need a relay, whatever your relay is doing could probably be done easier and straight to the point using a MOSFET load switch.

Comment: Okay ... Let us make it more simple ... My neice needs a school project. An AC/ DC bulb is to be switched on using two remote mobile phones. Time is not a factor. To eliminate the musical relay effect, can we use the power used for vibrator motor in a mobile? Ckt shud be as easy as for a kid to handle. Like using a couple of relays, bjts etc.

Comment: how will the behaviour of these lights work, will they stay on forever after being triggered? will they need a timer? How are you going to access the "power" from the phones?

Comment: I want to use the phones as a trigger only, no if the bulb switches off after the call ends.. No problem. Power can be drawn from a 6v-12v battery or AC 230 v socket. I will get the bulb accordingly.

Comment: it's not easy, as using the call (ring tone, speaker output) or the phone vibration events are only at the start. You will need an external timing circuit to hold the lights on for a certain time. The other issue is getting access to the phone signals, you will have to destroy the phones to get access to the vibration motor connections or the speaker connections.

Comment: I will use a basic phone .. Not an iPhone ;),.. Yes, I will break one phone to get the trigger signal. Okay, so we need a timer circuit for sure. Noted on that. Do you have a better idea? Using DTMF wud involve arduino ... That's going to be a headache. Hmm.. Anything like a ready to use vibration sensor which senses the vibration of the phone and activates a timer/relay/DC bulb/motor... Anything ?

Comment: @KyranF no need to destroy the phone just to get at the connections - you will have to open it, though.  With proper tools and care you can open a phone and reassemble it.

Comment: @JRE of course, but who knows what tools and methods will be used? Better to tell him that the phone used will most likely not be very good afterwards, then give false hope lol.

Comment: @PrathamKumar you try to use vibration sensors, or a microphone with a simple 'noise level' trigger for the 555 timer circuit etc. These are non-destructive methods. You can also assume the screen of the phone will light up during a call, and go dark after the call. Using a very simple Light dependent resistor (LDR), plus an operational amplifier to turn the LDR voltage into a useful signal, you can directly (using a high side power switch as shown by TJ's answer) turn on a light of some kind. It will turn off after the call and the screen goes dark. no need for timer ;)

Comment: Yes JRE .. I have opened an old Nokia set and looks I can solder out the vibrator from it and take two wires from it. It will never vibrate in future though.

Comment: KyranF ...LDR is a good idea ... I will take out the front cover of the phone and place the LDR inside near an LED. Thanksss a lot .. It wud work and cost effective and easy for a kid to understand and LDR.